# do superclass and subclass objects share the common method?

Tags: c#, oop

If I don't mark a method as `virtual`, will it be available to a derived class?

If using object `a`, I make changes to method of base class. Then object `b` accesses the same method `m1()` of the base class (which is available to derived class).

Will it print those changed value by object `a`?

Will they share common method ?

```
class A
{
    public int m(int i)
    {
        return i * i;
    }
}

class B : A
{
}

class C
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        int x = a.m(2);    // returns 4

        B b = new B();
        int y = b.m(4);    // 16
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you see when you debugged the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because the derived class is a type of the base class.

Consider a Mammal class. All mammals breathe, so we would have Mammal.Breathe(). Now consider a Cat class. Since cats are mammals, we would have this as derived from Mammal, then there is already a Cat.Breathe() inherited from Mammal, without any extra work (the "no extra work" bit being one time-saving aspect of OO).

If Mammal.Breathe() was virtual, then we could make it behave differently in the case of Cat.Breathe(). If it's not virtual, we cannot, though a non-virtual method can call a virtual method, which would make that part of its behaviour overridable.

Comment: I Got the point sir , your explanation is always of great avail........my out of above program are correct sir? i also want to know  if using object "b" i do some changes to method of super class and then i make a new object of A class then if i invoke the method on object "a" of super class which has already been changed using the base class object then a.m1() will get that changed method

Comment: We're back to the differences between hiding and over-riding again. I recommend you try the various possibilities and step through the code in a debugger. The explanations here and on your other questions have already covered the relevant theory, you need to get a *feel* for what actually happens in practice.

Comment: i learnt all explained by you, now i do my own practice .if i stucke somewhere then i revert back to you ...thanks for all your assistance and explaining in detail with example most of my doubts are clear now

Answer (score 1):

> if i don't use virtual to a method, will it be available to derived class?

Yes the method will be available to any derived classes but you won't be able to override this method in a derived class and change its behavior. In your example class `B` posses the `m1` method because it derives from class `A` but cannot override it as the method is not virtual.

<strike>As a matter of fact your example won't even compile because you didn't specify a return type for the `m1` method. Also by not specifying an [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) for the method, `private` will be assumed and you won't even be able to call the base method in derived classes (unless using reflection of course).</strike> (after edit by @dtb the code will now compile)